# Why can't Fantom find the resource in a jar?

Tags: java, resources, jar, fantom

I've recently gotten started using [Fantom](http://fantom.org/). I've got a jar file that contains a resource (svg image, in this case). I can use the classes from the jar just fine, but the resource won't load: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("name")` returns `null`. When I use this exact same jar in a Java-only context, it can find the resource just fine.

Any suggestions on how to debug or even solve this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about Fantom (looks cool from a quick glance though), but it seems there is some Classloader manipulation/isolation going on. Might have something to do with something in this area, for example: http://fantom.org/sidewalk/topic/1208.

Comment: Try addressing the resource with its full path starting with / and see if that helps.

Comment: What does the "full path" mean? The resource is in a jar file.

Comment: So if I undersand this correctly you want to access a .jar file from Fantom and that .jar file contains a svg? Or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong part is `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`

Java: `AnyClassFromJar.class.getClassLoader()` works

Fantom: `Class.forName("AnyClassFromJar").getClassLoader()` should work

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be in a Jar?  If you stick it directly in your Pod, you can use [access](http://fantom.org/doc/sys/Pod.html#file) files like this:

```
file := Pod.find("myPod").file(`/path/to/file.ext`)
```

Comment: It's in a jar I want to use, I don't have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, `.jar` files can't be accessed for resoruces but since `.jar` files are nothing more than Zip files with fancy extension you can open them like that.

Here is my folder structure for the example (but any structure will do).

```
ExampleDir
 |
 +--- TestZip.fan
 +--- testOpen.jar
       |
       +--- META-INF
       |     +--- email.png
       |     ...
       |...
```

And you open the `testOpen.jar` like this:

```
class TestZip
{
  static Void main(Str[] args)
  {
    jar := Zip.open(File(`testOpen.jar`))
    png := jar.contents[`/META-INF/email.png`].readAllBuf
    jar.close
  }
}
```

EDIT: Having a discussion about this on Fantom boards it seems that this example should work.

```
buff := Interop.toFan(Class.forName("net.testOpen.Foo").getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("email.png")),4096)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try '/name' instead of 'name'.  That works for me (in Java).